# RegEx: Repeated identical vowels in a string - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to only display those strings (name of manufacturers) that contain 2 or more identical vowels in Oracle11g. I am using a RegEx to find this.

```
SELECT manuf_name "Manufacturer", REGEXP_LIKE(manuf_name,'([aeiou])\2') Counter FROM manufacturer;
```

For example:
The RegEx accepts

```
OtterBox
Abca
abcA
```

The RegEx rejects

```
Samsung
Apple
```

I am not sure how to proceed ahead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle11g, but for someone to help you they'll want to know what happens if your string contains both `OtterBox` and `Samsung` || `Apple`.  Reject or Accept?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the output (and rejected strings) you have posted. When you say "2 or more identical vowels", is your objection that the `O` and `o` in `Otterbox` are not the same case, and hence technically "identical"?  Good luck.

Comment: @Jonathan - Otterbox is accepted because vowel 'o' is present twice. The check needs to be case-insensitive. I have updated the question to give more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
WITH mydata AS (
  SELECT 'OtterBox' AS manuf_name FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple' FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Samsung' FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM mydata
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(manuf_name, '([aeiou]).*\1', 'i');
```

I am not sure why you used `\2` as a backreference instead of `\1` -- `\2` doesn't refer to anything in this regex. Also, note the wildcard and quantifier `.*` to indicate that there can be any number of any character between the first occurrence of the vowel and the second. Third, note the `'i'` parameter to indicate a case-insensitive search (which I think is what you want since you say that the regex should match "OtterBox").

[**SQL Fiddle here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/2901)

Comment: I see your fiddle does work though, yet that regex doesn't work for me in just a regular expressions tester.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Could be the difference between POSIX ERE regular expressions (used by Oracle) and whatever regular expression engine you're using in your tester.

Comment: I understand now, having looked at your regex. You want the regex to capture the whole manufacturer name. That's not necessary here, I only care whether it matches.

Comment: Aah, makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

David yours wasn't quite working for me.  What about this?

```
\w*([aeiou])\w*\1+\w*
```

https://regex101.com/r/eE3iC2/3

EDIT:  updated one per suggestions:

```
.*([aeiou]).*\1.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/eE3iC2/5

Comment: Well, this doesn't work if they mix cases (so it will match otterbox, but not Otterbox).  I'm trying to figure it out.  EDIT:  Fixed now.

Comment: The above won't work for something like `Otter Box` because you're not taking non-word characters into consideration. https://regex101.com/r/eE3iC2/4

Comment: Couple things, you don't need the quantifier after the backreference (you've matched the character once in the capturing group, you only need to match it once more, and you'll want a wildcard instead of a word character class.

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now.